# how to put loading message in iframe before page was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a link  and when mouse is hovered over it, it's  content(src) will be loaded in iframe. I want to display loading message in iframe before the page get's loaded completely. Is it possible to put that message

Below is jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/tSwC6/3/

Regards.
Sukumar

Comment: most cases no, usually if you load iframe content from internet it becomes locked as read-only, some cases it can be even not readable (loading from foreign domain).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is hide the iframe and put a loading icon on #content, then when it is done with loading show the iframe again with using the onload event:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffreydev/tSwC6/4/

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
$("a").hover(function(){

  var href = $("a").attr("href");
  var loading = $('<div>loading....</div>').appendTo("#content");
  var iframe = $("<iframe src='"+href+"'>").appendTo("#content").hide().bind('onload',   
    function(){loading.hide(); iframe.show()});
 },                
 function(){
   $("#content").empty();
 }
);
```