# javascript for iframe - loading message and what to do if there is no connection

Tags: javascript, iframe

[how to put loading message in iframe before page was loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434967/how-to-put-loading-message-in-iframe-before-page-was-loaded)

I have used the suggestion on the link above to help solve my issue but it isn't really clean.

My problem:  I manage a large CMS and we want to have some content that not only requires login but requires that employees are on the local intranet.  So the CMS is internet and I have another local intranet server that will supply the content.

Employees go to the page and I have a clean iframe of the intranet site.  Only issue is that I don't want them to see the browser error message if they do not have connectivity.  I want them to see my error message because if they don't see mine our tech helpdesk will get a flood of calls.  I am using the above code right now and I can set a long time out on it but eventually people are going to see the "Unable to connect" message...  What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, but I cannot guarantee if it will work, as I have not tried it, but it makes sense to me.

If you're willing to sacrifice a HEAD request, then you could do something like this using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    async: true,
    url: "http://someurl.local",
    success: function(message,text,response){
        // Success, connectivity assured, load iframe
        $("#myiframe").prop("src","someurl.local");
    },
    error: function(response){
        // Show your error
        alert("Sorry, no connectivity, dont contact support please. :)");
    }
});
```

Comment: An alert really doesn't work because if they hit OK then they just see a big Unable to Connect iframe.  I need an area or image placeholder to put in the iframe until the website successfully loads.  So the problem is how do you tell the area or image to hide once my page loads?  Also I could add a script in the footer of the called page if this helps.

Comment: Well thats for you to code, right? I just provided the means for you to react on an error without having to deal with the error in the iframe. One way would be to have the iframe in a div, make it position relative, and then a div inside it with position absolute, and width and height = 100%. There you go. :)

Comment: Also I am getting the alert no matter if the page is accessible or not.

Comment: Check your console for the response from the AJAX request - you can use the complete event instead of success and error, and then parse the result, and take proper action.